# Implementing rules in a class python

Tags: python, python-3.x, rules, rule-engine

I am stuck on applying rules in a class like forcing some values to change if some rule is present and so on. However I am unable to pass rules to the class. Here is my code, and what i require:

```
class Item: 
    valid_item_dict = {"a":20, "b":30, "c":40, "d":50}
    def __init__(self, item_id):
        self.item_id = item_id
        self.item_cost = Item.valid_item_dict.get(self.item_id)

class checks:
    def __init__(self):
        self.content = list()
        
    def cheque(self, item):
        self.content.append(item)
        
    def totals(self):
        self.total = sum([self.item_counter().get(itm)*Item.valid_item_dict.get(itm) for\
                          itm in list(self.item_counter().keys())])
        return self.total
    
    def item_counter(self):
        self.item_count_list = [itms.item_id for itms in self.content]
        self.item_count_dict = dict((item, self.item_count_list.count(item)) for item in
                                     self.item_count_list)
        return self.item_count_dict

# Adding items to the list
item1 = Item("a")
item2 = Item("a")
item3 = Item("a")
item4 = Item("b")

# instatiance of class
cx = checks()
cx.cheque(item1)
cx.cheque(item2)
cx.cheque(item3)
cx.cheque(item4)

cx.totals()
>>> 90 (20*3 (from a) + 1*30 (from b))
```

In normal cases this works fine but I have a ton of rules which I need to add and I was earlier thinking of adding if-else rules in totals method of "checks" class. But is their a more generalized way to add these rules. Rule is something like if we have 3 types of product a, then the value of 'a' reduces from 20 to 10.
I did go over this question and am trying to use this, but any help would be wonderful. ([Python how to to make set of rules for each class in a game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55226942/python-how-to-to-make-set-of-rules-for-each-class-in-a-game))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use a more direct loop to implement these rules and make your code clearer. I find it easier to maintain complex logic than trying to code golf a 1-line result:

```
 from collections import Counter, namedtuple
 
 Rule = namedtuple("Rule", ["threshold", "newvalue"])
 """rule: if count is greater than or equal to threshold, replace with newvalue"""

 
 class Item:
    rules = {'a': Rule(3, 10)}

    ...

class checks:

    ...

    def totals(self):
        counts = Counter(self.content)
        self.total = 0
        for count in counts:
            value = Item.valid_item_dict[count]
            rule = Item.rules.get(count, Rule(0, value))
            if counts[count] >= rule.threshold:
                value = rule.newvalue
            self.total += value*counts[count]

        return self.total
```

I'm assuming you want the result of your sample to be 60 and not 90.

Comment: Yes wanted the result to be 60. I tried the code it's giving "KeyError: <__main__.Item object at 0x00000284FBC59108>" in line "value = Item.valid_item_dict[count]". However, i understand what you are trying to do here with updating the value in valid item dict to new value based on rule. However, is it genralized? I mean then how to implement a rule such as for every "d" as an item, you add "c" as free or for every 5 counts of b, only  3 will be counted towards total. Can i do this using this approach? Thanks for  the response and apologies for the delay in replying.

Comment: Sorry. I should have pointed out that this was a sketch and I didn't test it to the fullest. If you want mathematical rules then your ruleset can pull from the operator module and include that (i.e. `{"a": (operator.gte, 3, 10)}`) and then update the code to refer to the operator in the rule. For more complex rules, you need a more complex parseable language or code. (i.e `{"b": (gte, 5, "add c")}` but then you need to account for those values and handle them correctly). You should be able to generalize it in a similar fashion.

Comment: Thanks @Josh English. Got it to work using operators and the whole idea of updating values using parsing for complex rules. Will improve it further but it's generalized enough for now. Thanks.